# Recover From Twilio Flow Gather Input Hangup

Tags: asp.net, twilio, twilio-flow

I have a use case to receive a voice call, take a message, transcribe it, and send it by SMS.

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

I have tried this a couple ways and run into a issue in each case.

1. I can record Voicemail but am stuck as to how to transcribe the .mp3 file to test in order to SMS it to the recipient.
2. I can Gather Input on Call and get a transcription but if the caller hangs up after leaving the message, the flow terminates and I cannot forward the message to an SMS recipient.  If the caller does not hang up and presses the #-key, I can send the transcribed text to the SMS recipient, although I do not have an .mp3 file recorded. (Less of an issue)

Possible Solutions:

1. (Best in my opinion) Add a "Hangup" transition to the Gather Input on Call Widget so that the flow can continue.
2. Have a function that I can transcribe the .mp3 file from Record Voicemail and respond with the text to be sent to the SMS recipient.
3. Provide a Flow Widget Variable for the transcribed Voicemail to be forwarded to the SMS Recipient.
4. Provide a way that a Call Status Changes webhook API can access the Flow Variables that were just completed.  (I could probably send them myself after a Gather Input on Call if it did not terminate on a Hangup.)